# How to add webpart zone at master page in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, navigation, custom, custom-masterpage, web-part-zone

How to **add webpart zone at master page in sharepoint 2013**.
Isn't it possible?

Be added to webpart zone -> used be a webpart in the custom left navigation bar.

Comment: Web part zones can not be added onto the master pages.  Master pages are supposed to contain common components for all SharePoint pages.

Comment: Then, How to use custom left navigation using css?               I'd like to use custom left navigation for all sharepoint pages.

Comment: You can develop a user control and build a feature that can tell Master page to use your user control in the left nav.